# how can i get the key and value separately in dictionary python by slicing

Tags: python, dictionary, slice

I have a dictionary below :

```
{"product17":[3,"600I Infusion Pump",255]}
```

Simply, I need the key and value separately. after getting the value separately, I need also to slice the list. but I can not get key and value separately. how can I get the key and value separately in dictionary python by slicing?

Comment: Please clarify, why can you not use `dict.keys()` function? Getting all keys, and the you can get the value for each key.

Comment: ok thank i am going to use that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `d.items()` on your dictionary to iterate over `(key, value)`-tuples. Combined with `zip`, you can get keys and values:

```
d = {...}  # your dictionary
keys, values = zip(*d.items())

# slice values
```

Example:

```
d = {f"k{i}": f"v{i}" for i in range(3)}
keys, values = zip(*d.items())
keys   # ('k0', 'k1', 'k2')
values  # ('v0', 'v1', 'v2')
```

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary can be convert to 2 lists. first list will be for all keys and another for values. We can convert like below:

method 1 (using zip):

```
dict1={A:'1', B:'2'}

# using zip()
list1, list2 = list(zip(*dict1.items()))

---------------------------------------------
print(list1)>>(A,B)
print(list2)>>(1,2)
```

method 2(using items):

```
dict1={A:'1', B:'2'}
list1=[]
list2=[]

#using items()
for i in dict1.items():
list1.append(i[0]), list2.append(i(1))


---------------------------------------------
print(list1)>>(A,B)
print(list2)>>(1,2)
```